# Java: Write to an OutputStream though File

Tags: java, file, md5, outputstream

I am not sure if this is achievable.

I have a third party library which has a function that accepts a `File`:

```
String function(File file);
```

This  function will simply download some contents from the cloud and write to that file.

Now, I have got a special `OutputStream` which calculate the MD5 of the file internally. While the data goes through the stream, the MD5 is calculated.

Since I cannot change the signature of the library, is there anyway I can still use the function which accept a File, but let the data go pass though my `OutputStream`?

Comment: Since you're the one who invokes both these methods, wouldn't you have access to the `file` object?

Answer (score 1):

Not in a platform independent way using the standard API.

In *nix (and perhaps windows as well), you could create a LIFO-file, which you pass to the library function, and which you can read yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source of the lib, modify it and compile the JAR file.
An output stream does not mean that this is a file. It could be anything.

Comment: You're assuming that the library is open source.

Comment: Yes, there is no point using a closed source lib to compute the MD5 checksum.

Comment: The library doesn't do the md5 computation. Reread the question.

Comment: One could wrap the outputstream to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not access the library's source code you have no choice but to read the file after the library function has written it. Provided, of course, that the library does not provide a function to write to an OutputStream instead of directly using a file.